# Python Split Operator

Tags: python

I want to split the following on the following basis:-

```
a = '"64 213121\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n64 91547531\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n"'
```

I want only `[213121,40771494536,91547531]`, ie I want to split on the basis of `\r\n\r\n` plus sthe unique number `64`. This 64 can be some other integer as well.

I'm currently doing like this:-

```
    a = a.split('\r\n\r\n')
    temp_a = []
    for i in a:
        try: #using try because sometimes , the split function returns '', which cannot be spliited further and hence nothing at index 1 position.
            i = i.split(' ')[1]
            temp_a.append(i)
        except : pass
```

Any better pythonic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want is just a more pythonic one?

```
print [x.split(' ')[1] for x in a.split('\r\n\r\n') if len(x) > 1]
```

result:

```
['213121', '40771494536', '91547531', '40771494536']
```

just use your split method,more pythonic.

if you do not need the duplicate numbers,use this:

```
print list(set([x.split(' ')[1] for x in a.split('\r\n\r\n') if len(x) > 1]))
```

result:

```
['91547531', '213121', '40771494536']
```

Answer (score 0):

Pythonic way:

```
>>>a = "64 213121\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n64 91547531\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n"
>>>list(set(a.replace('\r\n\r\n',' ').split(' ')[1::2]))
['91547531', '213121', '40771494536']
```

using regex:

```
>>> a = "64 213121\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n64 91547531\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n"
>>> [ x for x in re.findall('\d+',a) if len(x)>2 ]
['213121', '40771494536', '91547531', '40771494536']
```

simply:

```
>>> re.findall('\d{3,}',a)
['213121', '40771494536', '91547531', '40771494536']
```

here i am using `{n,m}` in regex with match from m to n repetations
example a{2,} will match `aab` means two or more repeatation or a

Comment: you got your expected output??

Comment: No. Thats because, its valid only for 2 digit `64`, what if its 3 digit `128` or 4 digit `1000`. What in that case?

Answer (score 0):

There's two optative parts, first and last 64, so put in optative group `?`
The middle group should contain a number `\d` and some trailings `[\r\n]+`

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = '"64 213121\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n64 91547531\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n"'
>>> re.findall(r'[64\s]?(\d+?)[\r\n]+[64]?', test)
['213121', '40771494536', '91547531', '40771494536']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '"64 213121\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n64 91547531\r\n\r\n64 40771494536\r\n\r\n"'
b = [int(s) for s in a.split() if (s.isdigit() and s != '64')]
```

This will help to achieve what you want.

Explanation:

It checks whether the string that is split is a digit and whether it is no equal to '64', then it converts it to a string.